# Implementing "below the fold" in a bootstrap 5.1 page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a web using bootstrap and I need to implement, ideally using css, a "below the flow" positioning for a footer.
Actually, I'm calling it "below the fold" but maybe it's not the right name to use.

What I want to do is, after loading the page, show only the top of the footer at the bottom of the page (a little bit to give a clue to the user about the footer existence). Then, the user can scroll down and check the footer.

Of course, it should work in mobiles as well.

I was googling but I did not find anything, maybe because I'm looking for using a wrong name.

Next a wire-frame trying to describe what I mean:

[image]

And also a sample that is near to work, but it is not showing the little bit of the footer that I want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Below the fold</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <form action="/search">
                        <div class="row mt-10 gx-0">
                            <div class="col pe-0">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="visually-hidden" for="categories">Categories:</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="categories">
                                        <option selected>Category 1</option>
                                        <option disabled>Category 2 - coming soon</option>
                                        <option disabled>Category 3 - coming soon</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9 ps-0">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                                    <input
                                            id="query"
                                            name="cards[query]"
                                            type="text"
                                            autocorrect="off"
                                            autocapitalize="off"
                                            autocomplete="false"
                                            spellcheck="false"
                                            required="true"
                                            maxlength="512"
                                            aria-label="Search"
                                            placeholder="Search here ...."
                                            class="form-control"
                                    />
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-border text-body" type="submit" title="Search">
                                            <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer style="background-color: black">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Below the fold?

Comment: @angelcervera It should be "below the viewport" actually :) Your concept of positioning of the footer seems pretty simple to me. If you can share the codes here then we can help you.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam it’s a well known term, pinched from the print world https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Above_the_fold

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry, You are right. "below the fold" is what I tried to say. :(

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam Shared an example that is "near" to work. The footer in below the fold, but I want to show a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a negative margin top on the footer will do it perfectly. Because the `container` on the top section already has 100 viewport height.

```
<footer style="background-color: black; margin-top: -35px;">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Below the fold</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <form action="/search">
                        <div class="row mt-10 gx-0">
                            <div class="col pe-0">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="visually-hidden" for="categories">Categories:</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="categories">
                                        <option selected>Category 1</option>
                                        <option disabled>Category 2 - coming soon</option>
                                        <option disabled>Category 3 - coming soon</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9 ps-0">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                                    <input
                                            id="query"
                                            name="cards[query]"
                                            type="text"
                                            autocorrect="off"
                                            autocapitalize="off"
                                            autocomplete="false"
                                            spellcheck="false"
                                            required="true"
                                            maxlength="512"
                                            aria-label="Search"
                                            placeholder="Search here ...."
                                            class="form-control"
                                    />
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-border text-body" type="submit" title="Search">
                                            <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer style="background-color: black; margin-top: -35px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
            <div>
                Bla
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```